# Is there application of the set $\prod_{i\in\mathbb R}\mathbb R$?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, vector-spaces, banach-spaces

The set  $$\prod_{i\in\mathbb R}\mathbb R$$ has cardinality larger than  $\mathbb R$, in most occasion, it has been a "theoretic object" with little practical use. I wonder is there any example or situation where it is treated as "the background for something to happen"? (perhaps, when do we treat it as a vector space, topological space or banach space where interesting things happen on it, or consider differentiation or integration of real functions defined on it?)

Comment: I heard about applications to infinite-dimensional vector spaces, ie [Hilbert Spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_space), mostly in physics. For instance, canonical commutation relations such as [x,p] = i  can be realized only on an inﬁnite-dimensional Hilbert space.

Comment: Is this not $\Bbb R^{\Bbb R}$, the set of functions from $\Bbb R$ to $\Bbb R$?

Comment: No, I would like to consider the cartesian product of $\mathbb R$

Comment: Jason, regarding your comment beginning with "No", see the remarks that begin with "*The special case Cartesian exponentiation occurs when all the factors* $X_i$ *involved in the product are the same set* $X$" at [this web page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product#Infinite_products).